# Please help me understand part of Gemoro Makkos 12b

Tags: murder, trees, city-of-refuge, maseches-makos

I do not understand the Gemoro [Makkos 12b](https://www.sefaria.org/Makkot.12b.4?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi&with=Ritva&lang2=he)

The Gemoro deals with the case of a “blood redeemer” (BR) and an “accidental killer” (AK). A tree is on the border of the city of refuge; the trunk in one location and the branches in another. Rabbi Yehudah holds that the location of the branches determines the law for the whole tree. This creates a problem when the trunk is inside the city of refuge. If we follow the principle that the location of the branches fixes the law, it will be allowed to kill the AK at the trunk inside the refuge city which seems most unreasonable.

Rava said that it can be explained as follows: In the case where its trunk is inside the boundary and its boughs outside, and the AK was standing at its trunk, everyone agrees that the BR may not kill him, and when Rabbi Yehuda said that the trunk follows the boughs, he did not intend to include that case.

If the AK is standing among the boughs of the tree, and the BR is able to kill him with arrows and pebbles, everyone, including the Rabbis, agrees that the BR may kill him, as the boughs are outside the city.

Why does the gemoro require arrows and pebbles? Why cannot the BR kill the AK directly?

Answer (score 2):

The Gemara seems to be describing a scenario where the only way to reach the branches are through the trunk. However, if the BR can circumvent the route of having to go through the trunk then the trunk is meaningless to him, whereas if he'd have to go by way of the trunk he can't consider that spot to be outside the city boundary, according to Chachamim.

To illustrate this point we are speaking of a tree whose branches are too high to reach directly. This is a more direct illustration of the difference, rather than discussing two types of trees: the variable is the action rather than the scenario.